# Org-Wide Sharing Settings is Private, expose records to community users

Tags: customer-community, org-wide-defaults

We have setup our organization with Org-Wide Sharing settings as Private and then use Managed Apex sharing to share records with users.

We now have a need to expose these records to Customer Community Login Users and enable them to create a certain records.

How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You won't be able to do it using Apex Sharing which suggests to me that you'll want to start from scratch and rethink your original sharing model. You can enable the External Sharing model, but I suspect that won't solve the issues you'll be faced with.

I recommend [Getting Started with Communities](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://help.salesforce.com/help/pdfs/en/salesforce_communities_implementation.pdf) and [Security Implementation Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.securityImplGuide.meta/securityImplGuide/) as resources.

Comment: Can't we use CustomObject__Share object record to share record with specific user? just a thought!

Answer (score 1):

We resolved this issue by creating custom community pages that exposed the relevant records by setting the `without sharing` keyword on the page controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable External Sharing option. Also through the Sharing settings you can enable access to Roles under Community Portal.

Comment: Only Partner Portal Users have Roles, Customer Portal Users do not. They only have a Profile.